# HTTPS generates back-end issues

Tags: ssl, typo3, typo3-4.5

One of my old website is running TYPO3 v4.5.
I bought a SSL certificate and my sys admin installed it on the server.

- the front-end is running well on https
- tha back-end login form runs weird : one time my login/password are ok, but sometimes it doesn't allow me to enter the back-end.

[image]

It is totally random and in Firebug, I have no clue in the console or in the network tab to help me. Same behavior for Chrome, FF or IE.

I tried a lot of parameters :

- [BE]LockSSL = 1
- [SYS][reverseProxyIP] with " *.*.*.* "
- [SYS][reverseProxySSL] with " * "
- [SYS][cookieSecure] = 1

I event tried a lot of different combinations, with no success.
**Please notice that I also get a TYPO3 6.2 website and those parameters work perfectly on it**. I guess that I am missing somthing for v4.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the BE cookieDomain configuration!

Comment: [BE]cookieDomain, [FE]cookieDomain and [SYS]cookieDomain are empty.

Comment: Try setting the BE cookieDomain settings according to your domain.